# Parse Json C# a objeto

Tags: c#, json

Como seria la mejor forma de parsear este Json?

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A9-6o99kcIqRM3CEaXxYwh_Dv-vUkvnM/view?usp=sharing

Lo intente asi, pero no me duelve datos

```
var resultJson2 = Json.deserialize<List<ClimaHour>>(result.Result);
public class ClimaHour {
    public  List<int> couldCover { get; set; }
    public  List<string> dayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public  List<string>dayOrNight { get; set; }
    public  List<int> expirationTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public  List<int> iconCode { get; set; }
    public  List<int> iconCodeExtend { get; set; }
    public  List<int> precipChance { get; set; }
    public  List<string> precipType { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> pressureAltimeter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Podrias poner el ejemplo del Json que queres en la pagina? muchos no pueden acceder a esos drives, y tambien existe la posibilidad de que desaparezca...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En teoría sólo deberías leer el contenido del json, guardarlo en un `string` y pasar esa variable para su *deserialización*.

```
string jsonPath = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(json);
var jsonD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClimaHour>(jsonPath);
```

Lo único extraño que note en tu pregunta, fue que estas tratando de deserializar un listado (`List<ClimaHour>`) de `ClimaHour` cuando sólo debería ser un `Objeto`.

Otra cosa es que usas **Json.deserialize**... busqué esa librería y no la encontré =/ , por eso la respuesta que dí es utilizando [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Ahora, como indicas una `url` para dicho **JSON** y éste se encuentra en *Google Drive*, debemos construir una función que devuelva una url válida para la deserialización del json.

```
Helpers helper = new Helpers();
using (var web = new WebClient())
{
   string data = string.Empty;
   string url = helper.GetGoogleDriveDownloadLinkFromUrl("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A9-6o99kcIqRM3CEaXxYwh_Dv-vUkvnM/view");
   data = web.DownloadString(url);
   var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClimaHour>(data);
}
```

Y la implementación del método `GetGoogleDriveDownloadLinkFromUrl`, que se encuentra dentro de la clase `Helpers`

```
public class Helpers
{
   public string GetGoogleDriveDownloadLinkFromUrl(string url)
   {
      int index = url.IndexOf("id=");
      int closingIndex;

      if (index > 0)
      {
         index += 3;
         closingIndex = url.IndexOf('&', index);

         if (closingIndex < 0)
            closingIndex = url.Length;
      }
      else
      {
         index = url.IndexOf("file/d/");

         if (index < 0)
            return string.Empty;

            index += 7;
            closingIndex = url.IndexOf('/', index);

            if (closingIndex < 0)
            {
               closingIndex = url.IndexOf('?', index);

               if (closingIndex < 0)
                  closingIndex = url.Length;
            }
       }
       return $"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={url.Substring(index, closingIndex - index)}";
     }
  }
```

No puedo llevarme todo el crédito y menciono que la función que crea la url la extraje de [este link](https://gist.github.com/yasirkula/d0ec0c07b138748e5feaecbd93b6223c); la forma de llamar a dicha función puede ser creando una clase (como lo hice yo) o dentro de la misma clase que lee el `JSON`, eso lo dejo a tu criterio colega

Comment: Me funciono, pero como consulto una URL quite la linea de string jsonPath = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(json);.

Comment: No sería mejor guardar el contenido del json como un recurso local de tu aplicación?

Comment: ese Json cambia dia a dia

Comment: Edito la respuesta :)

Comment: Si, lo guardo dia a dia para solo consultarlo una vez por dia. y que este disponible durante ese dia.